# why is return value of javascript function undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a function to detect the size of an image, and I want it to return an object that contains both the width and height.  In the code below, sz.width and sz.height *within* the function hold the values, but after they return the value it's undefined.  What am I missing?

```
     function getImgSize(imgSrc) {
        var newImg = new Image();

        newImg.onload = function() {
          var height = newImg.height;
          var width = newImg.width;

          function s() {}
          sz = new s();
          sz.width = width;
          sz.height = height;
          $('#infunc').text("in function, w = "+sz.width+", h = "+sz.height);
          return sz;
        }
        newImg.src = imgSrc; // this must be done AFTER setting onload
      }

var sz = getImgSize("http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-1920-1920-4.jpg");
$('#outfunc').text("outside function, w = "+sz.width+", h = "+sz.height);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/forgetcolor/LbxA3/

Comment: You are not the first to try to use async code in sequential context. Not the last either :)

Comment: Besides that you don't return anything, won't the image load function run after the image has been loaded, whereas getImgSize would return before then? (I'm not sure how the image loading stuff works.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `getImgSize` sets up the image loading and then terminates.  Later, when the image loads, the anonymous onload function is invoked and correctly calculates the size, then returns it, to an uncaring DOM engine...

You're probably wondering how you *can* do what you want.  Short answer: you can't.  Here's the closest you can get:

```
  function getImgSize(imgSrc, callback) {
    var newImg = new Image();

    newImg.onload = function() {
      ... // blah-blah blah
      callback(sz);
    }
    newImg.src = imgSrc;
  }
  getImgSize("http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-1920-1920-4.jpg",
            function(sz) {
              $('#outfunc').text("in callback, w = "+sz.width+
                                 ", h = "+sz.height);
            });
```

I actually came here to write:

> // this must be done AFTER setting onload

That's what I bet your problem was.
 // this must be done AFTER setting onload

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done. You're trying to get a return value of an async call.

Consider:

```
var i = 0;
setTimeout(function() { i = 1; }, 1000); //1 second later
alert(i);
```

That will alert `0` because the value only gets changed in one second and not right away.

#### [don't believe me?](http://jsfiddle.net/a4b5s/)

What you're trying to do is the same thing. you can't use a value that didn't happen yet. In order to accomplish what you're trying to, you need to use callbacks.