# Javascript / jquery function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do this:

```
test();

function test(){
  $('img').load(function(){
  alert(this.width);
 })
}
```

An alert is shown with the correct image width.

But, when I do this:

```
alert(test());

function test(){
  $('img').load(function(){
  return this.width;
 })
}
```

... the alert shows 'undefined'

Both examples are run from within the $(document).ready function. I think it got something to do with load(). But I can't figure out why alert works, but return doesn't.

thx!

Comment: What are you expecting, a function returns undefined when nothing else is returned, and returning from the callback does not return anything from test() ?

Comment: Your function `test()` doesn't return anything only your `img.load` returns and that is async as well..

Comment: This will never work because it's async. This is about ajax, but the explanation applies to your case too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694779/why-is-return-value-of-javascript-function-undefined?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Your `test` function always returns `undefined` because it doesn't have `return` statement.

`return` in your code belongs to the anonymous callback function.

Comment: So, what's your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a JS ninja yet but I feel this has something to do with scopes. Im suspecting the this keyword in both situations are pointing to different objects.

final: in the second example at the moment alert is called, there is nothing to return to it for it to display anything. This is because the return is defined asynchronously; it will return whenever the image is finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

Images are loaded asynchronously, so you better forget about `return` in this case. (See a detailed explanation at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)).

If you have to handle the image's dimensions after loading, do it from the callback:

```
function test(){
    $('img').load(function(){
        // If you need to use this.width or this.height, do it from here
    });
}
```

You can also pass a callback to test:

```
function test(callback){
    $('img').load(callback);
}
function doSomething() {
    alert(this.width);
}
test(doSomething);
```